# How extract array from string json?

Tags: php, json

I have this string :

```
$string =  '{"2r0ij":{"id":"2r0ij","title":"Official Reddit announcements","subscribers":7225390}}'
```

and I want convert to array. I tried with json_decode($string), but result is null. Same result with print_r($string).

What is wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/json_decode If result is null, the json string is invalid.

Comment: Show your actual code/attempt. `json_decode` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use `json_decode()` with the 'true' flag -

```
$string =  '{"2r0ij":{"id":"2r0ij","title":"Official Reddit announcements","subscribers":7225390}}';
$foo = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($foo);
echo $foo['2r0ij']['title'];
```

The result is:

```
Array ( [2r0ij] => Array ( [id] => 2r0ij [title] => Official Reddit announcements [subscribers] => 7225390 ) ) 
Official Reddit announcements
```

Here is a working [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/3pwh-zbqr). The string, minus the opening and closing quotes, validates at JSONLint.

Comment: SO, I have this code:         var_dump($profileuser->wp_reddit_info);
        var_dump(json_decode($profileuser->wp_reddit_info));

Comment: end result is: string(3603) "{"2r0ij":{"id":"2r0ij","title":"Official Reddit announcements","subscribers":7225390}}"
NULL

Comment: @marius You made the value shorter? Because `var_dump()` shows the length of the string is 3603 which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I deleted from response

Comment: @marius I see. `json_decode()` returns `null` when JSON is not valid. Please validate your JSON string here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I copied the string that you posted straight away and it parsed OK with `json_decode()`

Comment: I do not realize what has

Comment: @marius The code you posted works. We can help you only if you can create a reproducible example.

Comment: I know it's ok, but I can not figure out why in this situation does not work.

Comment: Is a wordpress textarea. This is all code: <tr>
 <th><label for="reddit_info"><?php _e('Reddit info'); ?></label></th>
 <td><textarea name="reddit_info" id="reddit_info" rows="15" cols="30"><?php 
        echo $profileuser->wp_reddit_info;
        var_dump(json_decode( $profileuser->wp_reddit_info));
        
         ?></textarea><br />

</tr>

Comment: result of var_dump is null and echo result : {"2r0ij":{"id":"2r0ij","title":"Official Reddit announcements","subscribers":7226053},"2qh33":{"id":"2qh33","title":"funny","subscribers":7206318},"2qh0u":{"id":"2qh0u","title":"/r/Pics","subscribers":7131807},...,"2ti4h":{"id":"2ti4h","title":"For things that are, you know, mildly interesting.","subscribers":2066765}}NULL

Comment: Please edit your original post to add code. Don't dump in comments where they're unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it to array, you need to set the second parameter of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to `true`:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: I made hundreds of jsons like that, but I realize now what's null.